# Linking to a native library in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, path, library-path

I have a native library to which I'm trying to link from Eclipse. Library (libhmsbeagle) is in /usr/local/lib:

```
$ls /usr/local/lib

libhmsbeagle-cpu.la             libhmsbeagle-jni.la
libhmsbeagle-cpu.so             libhmsbeagle-jni.so
libhmsbeagle-cpu.so.21          libhmsbeagle.la
libhmsbeagle-cpu.so.21.0.0      libhmsbeagle.so
libhmsbeagle-cpu-sse.la         libhmsbeagle.so.1
libhmsbeagle-cpu-sse.so         libhmsbeagle.so.1.1.1
libhmsbeagle-cpu-sse.so.21      libproxychains4.so
libhmsbeagle-cpu-sse.so.21.0.0  pkgconfig
libhmsbeagle-cuda.la            python2.7
libhmsbeagle-cuda.so            python3.4
libhmsbeagle-cuda.so.21         R
libhmsbeagle-cuda.so.21.0.0     site_ruby
```

In Eclipse "Run Configurations" I set as VM arguments:

```
-Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib
```

Eclipse fails to load the library. This looks like an Eclipse problem to me, because when I package the program as runnable jar and link the same library:

```
java -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib -jar app.jar
```

it is loaded.